# Flot::Highlight Point in Time series graph

Tags: javascript, flot

I am using most beautiful javascript plotting plugin `flot` for depicting some real time data with the help of line chart.

And I have following set of options:

```
{
          colors: ['#7999BB'],
          grid: { borderWidth: 1, borderColor:"#4572A7"},
          xaxis:  {
                   axisLabel: "Time (H:M)",
                   axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
                   axisLabelFontSizePixels: 11,
                   axisLabelFontFamily: 'sans-serif',
                   axisLabelPadding: 9,

                   mode:"time",
                   tickSize: [25, "minute"],
                   tickLength:5,
                   tickFormatter: function (v, axis) {
                   var date = new Date(v);
                   var hours = date.getHours() < 10 ? "0" + date.getHours() : date.getHours();
                   var minutes = date.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + date.getMinutes() : date.getMinutes();
                   var seconds = date.getSeconds() < 10 ? "0" + date.getSeconds() : date.getSeconds();
                   return hours + ":" + minutes;
                }
            },
            series: { shadowSize: 0,
                      lines: {
                              show: true,
                              lineWidth: 1.2,
                              fill: true,
                              fillColor: { colors: [ { opacity: 0.3 }, { opacity: 0 } ] }
                       }
                    },
            yaxis:  { show: true,
                      min:0,
                    }
}
```

Everything is working fine. But I want to highlight single point in graph.I tried using

```
plot.highlight(seriesIndex,dataPoint);
```

I did

```
plot.highlight(0, 99);
0 -  I have just single series.
99 - I am plotting 100 points and lets say for example I want to highlight 99th point.
```

No error on console.
But it's not working? How do I highlight point in time series graphs?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please show more of your code (how are you calling the plot and highlight methods?). And do you get an error  in your console?

Comment: @Raidri Please check updated code.I have no errors on my console.Graphs is getting plotted as it should.But Its not highlighting point.

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle ([link](http://jsfiddle.net))? For me `plot.highlight()` is working and I don't see an error in the code you have shown.

Comment: Did you try using time series? Cuz its also working for me if I do it w/o time series.I will try re creating in fiddle.

Comment: Yes I'm using time series too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long waste research n unnecessary panic I found a solution.Actually the issue was related to flot version.It worked fine with latest `flot 0.8.1.`  plugin.Thanks for your precious time and help.